# how to avoid to write multiple id of textview in array

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm writing a project for school. I'm looking for a method to avoid the initialization of the text views 63 times. I have a class called Cell where I have to insert the index e the id of the textview, but I don't know how to initialize the array with the for like this:

```
for(i in 0 until 63)
 cells.add(Cell(index, name_of_textview)) // for 63 times
```

I'm searching a method like that to avoid to write 63 times this:

```
cells.add(Cell(index, name_of_textview))
```

Comment: wouldn't using recyclerview be better here just add view in OnBind of the adapter

Comment: and there isn't a method I can use without using the recyclerview ?

Comment: well we can make custom view in which constructor takes 3 input : id of the view, index and number of views  and just in the custom view loop trouught the number of view and add index with id to make the views id that can be an option

Comment: ok but my textview id are called txt_cell_numberofcell (1,2,3 ... 63) there's a method to concate txt_cell_.{i} like this? so I can avoid writing useless code

Comment: without the code i cant help . yeah there is concat method for string for sure

Comment: for(i in 0 until 63)
            cells.add(Cell(i+1, txt_cell_numberOfCell)

Comment: that was already in the question and what can i get from this. whats cell() whats the composition of that method

Comment: constructor(index: Int, textviewCell: TextView){
       this.index = index
        this.textviewCell = textviewCell
    }

Comment: Are you using synthetic binding to reference `name_of_textview`?

Comment: no I'm using a plugin called kotlin-extension